# Radcombobox loses value when clicked on another control

Tags: wpf, vb.net, radcombobox

Two comboboxes - the user makes a selection in the first which provides a default value for the 2nd.  This works well until a series of keystrokes happen.  If the 2nd gets the focus, but not changed, then the first gets the focus, the default value disappears for the 2nd.

What would cause the default value disappear?

I suspect the second combo is not set up correctly but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="cboGlaze" FontSize="16" Background="#F6F8FA" BorderBrush="#D7D8DD" 
ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
Text="{Binding glaze, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
telerik:TextSearch.TextPath="Glaze" 
IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True"
Style="{DynamicResource RadComboBoxStyle3}" >

<telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Glaze}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding pctUpcharge}"  Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
 </telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Binding to the property "glaze" is handled in the DropDown event for the first combo.

Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: What is the DataContext of the RadComboBox and what kind of property is "glaze"?

Comment: Datacontext:              da.Fill(dt)
            thisCombo.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView

Comment: Property:      Private _glaze As String
    Public Property glaze As String
        Get
            Return _glaze
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _glaze = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("glaze")
        End Set
    End Property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind the `SelectedValue` property of the `RadComboBox` to the `glaze` source property and set the `SelectedValuePath` property to "Glaze" provided that the `DataTable` contains a column with this name:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="cboGlaze" FontSize="16" Background="#F6F8FA" BorderBrush="#D7D8DD" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
    SelectedValuePath="Glaze"
    SelectedValue="{Binding glaze}" 
    telerik:TextSearch.TextPath="Glaze" 
    IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True"
    Style="{DynamicResource RadComboBoxStyle3}" >
...
```